# How to parse and scrape the content of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, domdocument, custom-wordpress-pages

Is it possible to have a custom function to truncate the contents of a `defined DIV` on a blog post page to use as the summary on the blog index page. So rather than using `$the_content` or `$the_excerpt` - Is it possible to create $the_customContent and have some PHP which checks the blog post page and collects the content of the div with class "ThisIsTheContentToUse" - reason for this is that my blog posts have content on the page above the content I want to be included as the blog summary on the blog index page - so either want to tell WP to ignore those blocks of content, or, probably easier - just tell WP where the content to truncate is - e.g. in the "ThisIsTheContentToUse" div... possible?

If so... how? Can't seem to find anything online that defines this custom functionality - surely I can't be the first person to want to do this...?

Would apply_filters make this possible?

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

So, The blog post is structured as:

```html
<div class="headerArea">
  <h2>The title is here</h2>
  <ul>
</div>
<div class="bullets">
  <li>Bullet 1</li>
  <li>Bullet 2</li>
  <li>Bullet 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="ThisIsTheContentToUse">
  <p>The content starts here</p>
</div>
```

So, currently with the basic `get_the_content`, the result is:

> `"The title is here Bullet 1 Bullet 2 Bullet 3 The content starts here"`

But what I want is just `the content of the "ThisIsTheContentToUse" div`.

So it would be:

> `"The content starts here"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways we could set this up, two of which are popular. We could use the php `DOMDocument` class as well as the good old favorite of mine `regular expressions`!

#### Using `DOMDocument`:

1. First, we get the content using `get_the_content` function.
2. Then, we'll read the content using `DOMDocument`.
3. And finally parse it.

```php
$test = get_the_content();

if (class_exists('DOMDocument')) 
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    $class_name = 'ThisIsTheContentToUse';// This is the class name of your div element

    @$dom->loadHTML($test);

    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

    foreach ($nodes as $element) 
    {
        $element_class = $element->getAttribute('class');

        if (substr_count($element_class, $class_name)) 
        {
            echo 'Using DOMDocument: ' . $element->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Which will output this:

[image]

---

#### Using `Regular Expressions`:

1. We use `preg_match` function.
2. This is the pattern `<div class="ThisIsTheContentToUse">([^w]*?)<\/div>`.

```php
$test = get_the_content();

preg_match('/<div class="ThisIsTheContentToUse">([^w]*?)<\/div>/', $test, $match);

$new_excerpt = $match[1];

echo 'Using regular expressions: ' . $new_excerpt;
```

Which will output this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - very comprehensive! I like your 2nd solution but... I rather simplified things in my example and there is a lot of <div> markup around rather than a easy to define <div> wrapping the content I want to lift... Is there a way to define this with css classes rather than a div name - e.g. so it would work with ".wrapper .inner .topContent .content" ?

Comment: Not a problem! Yes, there absolutely is! I gave you two **very powerful** tools to work with. You can expand upon my solutions for any specific situation. If you want to scrape and parse the content using `selectors` then you would need to look into the `domdocument xpath`. There are tons and tons of tutorials online. You would need to search for `php domdocument xpath`.

Comment: ok thanks. I hope I can work it out from your foundations.

Comment: Not a problem. You can do it, it's not rocket science! Remember, if you find yourself stuck at any moment, then feel free to ask questions. There are many world-class experts here on SO, who are willing to help.